# 1-1 generates a gas error in solidity

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix

Why does calling the `reset()` function return the error: `The transaction ran out of gas. Please increase the Gas Limit.` after the `start()` function is called?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >0.6.0;


contract A
{
    struct f
    {
        string name;
        int val;
    }

    mapping(uint => f) private j;

    function start() public
    {
        j[1].val = 8;
    }

    function see() public view returns(int)
    {
        return j[1].val;
    }

    function reset() public 
    {
        j[1].val = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, can you include all your smart contract code?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: out of gas
 The transaction ran out of gas. Please increase the Gas Limit.